# Text getting dissappear on using scroller in Vegalite

Tags: vega-lite, vega, vega-embed, vega-lite-api

I create a chart in Vegalite and add scroller on it (vconcat-1) scroller work fine but text get dissapper on apply(bind scroller on x axis) by using a code --           "scale": {"domain": {"param": "brush"}}, under the x axis .
I want text must be visible and scroller also work properly .[image: when i bind scroller on x axis text get dissapper][Editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgRghgxg1g5gJwPYFcB2ATEAuUBTADwAcEcQAhaeZdDAYQjQDcIBnOpAGyVIF8AaEFCRoAZgEs4OUBALjW0kJwhg8nAGIiALgGUtAT055FhEmQCCc1gBkVazWl0GjIASC3itRh08PHcIKak2CCW8gAqnt7aen6ubqLaJsTBID7h+kTGbkZweJiKwpwoALZoCgFBZNZ4eZgcxWWugsqqnJSsauJo-vgp1bX5GLZtHV09zUp2nA08yWYhNXXD07N8LdM+OuIAXr2B-YuDmCP2MbvZG21bzvtVR8unGjG3k61q1uIlnvOpS0NPThfH45aYAeVEok6Wl+A0e4Mh0Le4KI0E8+lhDwBKPEUHRyP0qBhATASC0WiQJUUjCgAAs5iFvhgMC43BSiNS0HSGSAmSzsm4eOJ8sS+gsQP9MGCEMLHJNWPoSqTOGDUXiDJiJccMDpFcrVbj8bw2VF9olHLEXJVDiBIl48Dc4m5WCgwB57Y6rWLUjpXe7ohbXsa3BgIFoIIoWMU8BUANqgBhGTAQBAAAgAstpaamAJIAETIACYAAzFgCcxYAjCBBDm0ABHFB4JsAfWE6GJhcrAA4ACyCACixDwUC0eAwbdQcuwhYArMWAGwCBMQJOhtOZxzZ-NF0sVws1kB1xvNvCTjs4LsAdm7g+Ho-H5+nhd73cLgnT4gQeCIFQXxdnStBAAOSQVMkFEVMACU8BKJAowqWdZwAZn7EAAAUvx-RDewXZDlxARMhhTDMs1zAsQhLcti2Qw9jybVt22fZDKwXO8sgfCcmM7K8F17AiiOTDcyJ3Si92LXs6IbBiz24y9K1nW8QCHDixy4qdOwXLSBNXYjhK3cjd2o2cpJPRiNMvJC0JUkc1KfYlkIk-D+BXNcSM3LRtwokAqIrBdTJk+zLy0st2Nsx85OwZDHLLHS3P0zzDLE6irwC08gpnK9C1C5T7zsyLoqvK84r00iDNEnzxO7NLzIvGctPfXLVIiiyook-iXMI3ShLKxKKt88satk1rC0LVCws4jKXyvZzXNKjyvKMstK2LIapoXbslJsyaCpLSsSp6haksq8tK2rWtpPSyLrxy7b8pG5DAIO9desW5LloPC6zOGuqxokib7t+q8aN4ABdNxUQQCASjjUA0Gh-wtWWBpSjQQ8oybHAOrhhGyAADTCGxpnMNA4BcQQMf8ABaCsCPhkpEclDBpVlGEKdXTGQlJclKWaHGGbhbFRjYcZjHZ6MyD5VlOvpxntSeNZ0Y5xGAGJS3V1a6dxrETk2c49iViXsErWaQFlwXdbaIFvjZkBKZwYstYFnWVjaCEoTwW37ZnWcnbl+E3aIQ0NXFzn9pl7WQAANTwBAPCgVdPh6NZzrt5WyDVmioCvMA+bNyOY7j3FE+6PA9GQGA8DzNhaVT73YyA4twYj53o9j+OS56cukErgB1cQME8uv0+Nv2yELjvOCTvA1k+tOjZATPkOz3Ox5CCfi6n0vu8r6vWFpOf6-7Xtm-5xGN4Treu60Cu8H7weD8NznTfN9f2836e1lo0PVacsAr0kmvNuRdL7Tx3lXGu3956cwbvwJuQCL6dzLjfHud8B6eSgd7cOZ9x7v1AaXNYkkf4Zz-gAvOr9gGTzASg3eNciHQP8LA+BLdz54KQeA++nl6FYKAUzXUSouAGnVBiYho8WHVFLnwvUXAn6I1YI2FMlwcGLEkdqfhyptgG1EbTcRIRwgpjyFoKRAjOCyLIPIlAijyGR30QgQxxiNEXDMdgHRyiQAAE1CZPBJmTMWDCHZAN9GAO04gjCK1ESAHgjA8jWNbnaAMWhwn+K5soWAsTEbxIdPrPxWCly6NtKacwQI4BowiVAEUsd0lkEyeEQgXsR4gCqXowpXJ6SkAiVLJR+c4mmjGECCYET2RNIKfaPMBBnGO3yUE-0WS5QROVFgIBmTPg2wmUs007skSiJLIEv0ppnGNN2W6U0WwnGiNYkA9MKYYCqjRCHZJ2DumM1Lpw2kzjCxAM8VYTJBz6JXQskAgm3z9kRMEi9I6O5AVeOmCsn4ojJluK+fIJ4sL6lGwRU8sgSKiZtE0TkkeJsoVWCeHi5xhL8lAuRasLgcx5mpJgMM7FCsaXtOSeAelwzKWsEiLAUl8LPmEx5TAPlySMUUKZiSs5DyxWR2xZkpJ3t2VUE5YK00CqGlgA5QK4FHpslkryW4rlmTTlaIeQazFIRKCwEQFOegLKDkqwHMhAc6h1D+SJfIAA4jKZmap8T8vydi71A9bnCLJR61gwa7XcFZYqlWGBkIJoTYywmUb1UL3jYmrNKarB5kpBAbozjYzFn4AuU+FqJQEPtRElWvYMALlnCoYZOgRwiGGFWmNDrVC9jAK+YZ6EkDdC0HWHoCB02c0XnWhtTbAmtswAOodI7Y7jtVt23t1UgELscGCFAY4x3VrZbW+tjbV5TLnRgLdWgd17pXRnNdfalkGM9inB1UAzp4ELIs-JtSCCJJZcPDNb7Kwfq-YiqC0TYKyGcWgFAnBOCfPA6TWChbREwbg4+uxz6WWHwabW1iyEIC0SWXU2eDrez4cI8Mq5CBhW0ggFkA5N9xDROlm46jtH6Nlyld7YG2r5ADtYB4EQaz8nUNvgwDkESaAFF4dvGhED95FsbuW8Vpc+mlwOf0vAVNuYUipLJ6+t9XnhtE6XWp5RxDCfOQZvAob-UPNncIE4cnxP0YOdJ0DFaW1OfbYZ1Be83miKYSpyO3m23T3UwMtlWmdNkj08289YnUHGes2enz09zOsEs6UhzaXwulzs-cnhFLoWBzuSI6VGHDHgICwBmBymquew4eg2uZKAB0Hzv1PqvX6gwdX-CPIobY6r8mAs4aNsFxrTgjMtfG2HDrU3Cv6DmwNiNAmhM5e9jKuJdSTX4qNgpTdg7HA+PJqK4jv6fBjOcbx79u3tB5gq1txzbaf1aD22S32eXMBvau+M0Rt23FhZ+-dxwj2RNuPSJkfbE7EziDADKYZxqXhxHmVwTzQ2TnaF7ngSQtI0UToWc2vZurAyo7ZUTo5MyfA47xwTxGlP8mlbOGTs7irGduOZ88RwtO4D44ORzitqrSe+DZxq9HwzhcJN5-ztHnAMeRwlXrVnMOGcS6AVa6gtqGDMDYLekIKtXVG-UK4UGggZnUmKWja04pMlFMkGjNwNI2majt60uYbhICdC0673pIsfduCKAyb01SseOEViGcZNvUiZOuwkPV0fQ8i9JTkYEooDi29NKiyYEEPbp-uCMowmzPbyhJ16DPPoy+XBAC6Y59pFaJ5CEEkJYT7XOirx9xvIBplh90E4tkdTff2je-ECmTmE7EnjIELkSAMDdCkAEKPMgrCKEQAPHAN8myCDX9G4PFf8app9RH7fPqluai5VGs-oI2inbuDaLl3jSbSymG0BvIeQgP+pZ26-LO+8Gy75-riv3lcB8Gnuflztnj-iqL1hiAAVzlfoIEQEgFlhtuAVYOttlpMPHMKk4nAcCrysAe4PsngREPsiaPXvaiQdymqm3ubr3qSlQcjhaP3gkMKPLmQGCu5CJAWIIKwDwOnhIGoFgCEOvs6JfPsBgPmoWgEJDNDGQAjigIpsaObtDmQGgJSN0KuKPiALSLjnzp2POBsPoJUtgFPvkMIHPqTIUJQaAKGFoKUGQH8rVHMkoNqNYY0OUJqEzCjE0FAZFnfuKErsLN7hplAW-vvi7Myt-iAdzn-gEX8PLMrnEciG0Nnl3kEWoNbCCDEcXvnjaBkSqIiCXlAWfukYkYHMHBiM6NItAeVl4WojUUIkaLwTUQwe-pWj0A4lwCni0SYuAuEQXpetesurQTXjURkAxukaossOojIsoTXuIYoFDEhjgGYTaJekuvut-s3EQfaGQJMLAcvvIKvj6hvggFviADvgMTaEGkfqMTvqUe0bcSGjASkWoLfpqEysTE-tXu8DMDYRER4lzsfi-moCpKkHYaUG1n8QANQADkAApHCYeH8Z3k8Vzj0aCVvKsl3l8akWARDMgZ4JgbiYTBgcJiaAQf-uifgTgQbOQeXgXnKmQXQRQZ2qSTqq3tEbsQkm0YCcycniwYIIIewSEE4T9C4awIsQEJISUAWmgFckvvyYhnkHKeMiGFIQqdIU8Sqcho7oIHsMgDgKIKuJ0M6PwTgGhpwCoZMSAAoo4J4GGOIEwAKIIHKTRooF7qLF4Wpv7qEcKaEqYiEDfIwKwJDCKIeBIHBuOGcRcUgK8VMT0AgSAEgUOpyL4pqJeh8awXBpmcdsOmgKOiCfvJxpqOxjoHRgxs6Lge0eWZWVxvSbwfJnmUOsMVsR7tWdSYCdPMZs6M2YmTPKMYJq5hyAOf0W5n2bfAFj6X5rQkoU2TNg-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-rIcDWTaDYobSFApDaOM+RYbDasR+SAF+erYjEjQBQREBa+YoGOL+ooCzbaN1qmAeG4AzYIEzSzchGzW4BzejeyeTSRv+pMBgEqQXr9g9uqYIBgEzTHaDloODvHswV2cnZdnqmyD+Q9S7YIFHiAAAO7XXKH4Co0L6gDO3p5u3hiYZaAS0+0gB+1hgOEzg9j8RB3XKgXBBh2-qkaR43WvYp1x4J1J02hmWx1g5VHClkWAlT0p2YnW1kA12HhF2l1Lnl3T6m1o2gBB593M1t0QUgB5jFipi80olwVWmE0BXE3GW60x3daD3WXEGHKF3SCM2u3H3yR9js090BBc34gi0N1LZe2C3nWu6y1Tk1zgOS1XVLkgMjZS1wOK1fXK0-UI0hCa3V7a3XkUK3m0j0JG356V1w2W1YMpn5nI322V292KC40FDYA308l03e3f32En0DQmRf24D-0ekh174F6IJXyDlU3yj9UhA+4QPTld4iNJZC0S3DkINrlyNsKiPNYPwK2fXfXYDlV-VkA4OHhAMahiKA1Qw61T4ENg20j+QPlGDG3Q271vnm3w0GO-nUN22dQO0gWCOH2MPCEsM2Xv0W0yk-3vRnR2V8Pd0CP70AnCPqOfzYYSOllSMaYyPHVqMgLsJHX7xwPKN9zXVZNUJ7WFMPyoM6MYN6Oq2UNGMVUJnhzmNXkg3WP60mT2NQ0V3OPkNW1522003eN0N+MMPX1RWslWghNKlu0DQS2HH8MpVxOh2AnyPrUIBEZ9WpNKDpPwNC2agrNnUBbrM7NoKIPtH7MrkqMG1YGVMq0XEr3YOwa4NA34ORyEPVQdOONdPAWkw9OUP9Mo3OP0OOWjME2sP7HsNhOcNLRVhRPADzNAtnOJOrOAIbO2nSPHOyOIvZMaO5NEOHVS17NIt3UtYovuA3OYPuMgBGMQzPMtOvM2OpQfOkPdOuMUOUv-NgyCDfh8GcCJUBAGXl4H1kDdAYA-hDARmouIwitiuYARnzEhnlCJAIAQVT5Rl7qKDa3yE2PI0UzCjF2KAlWaia42q0AR5uCb2qNCDaDymVK0OAvDMBCKrFL47eoQCz2hNHEVAsOeUcHdTgrcGHh8ERUBA+siFfqUvqHfDwymLzG6F05Ywlq8gAOgAmOwFASUuKIRg0sWMvOtyEOBuPmfM73fMuOmEW1W0FXKBjgUv3MgBDqxxRg6sl1FNWuOA2t8DgxAA)